# How to solve "Returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" (Actual depenecies between structs)

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, object-lifetime

I'm learning Rust (I'm a C++ dev) and I'm still getting used to the borrow checker.
I have the following example (which is also on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/z873x9cPn):

```
struct Foo {
    value: i32,
}

struct Bar <'a> {
    foo: &'a mut Foo,
}

struct Parent <'a> {
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Bar<'a>,
}

impl <'a> Bar <'a> {
    fn new(foo: &'a mut Foo) -> Self {
        Self {
            foo
        }
    }
}

impl <'a> Parent <'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut foo = Foo{ value: 2};
        let bar = Bar::new(&mut foo);

        Self {
            foo,
            bar,
        }
    } 
}

fn main () {
    let _parent = Parent::new();
}
```

But when trying to compile I get an error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `foo`
  --> <source>:27:9
   |
25 |           let bar = Bar::new(&mut foo);
   |                              -------- `foo` is borrowed here
26 | 
27 | /         Self {
28 | |             foo,
29 | |             bar,
30 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I've been looking through other posts but they don't solve exactly this dependency. Also, I've been trying to figure what to do but found no solution.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implemented this the same way in C++ that you did in Rust, you'd have undefined behavior.  Rust is actually saving you here.

`&mut foo` creates a reference to the function-local `foo`, but then you *move* `foo` into a new instance of `Parent`, and so the reference isn't valid anymore.  Rust catches this at compile time.  You cannot move or drop a value while there is a reference to it.

The *simplest* way around this from the perspective of complexity of implementation would be to use a reference-counted smart pointer ([`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)) which will give `Bar` and `Parent` *shared ownership* of the `Foo`.  (This is analogous to the C++ `std::shared_ptr` template, and has almost the same semantics.)

However, this is complicated by the fact that you are giving away *mutable* references to the `Foo`.  Rust does not allow you to obtain a mutable reference to the value held by an `Rc` unless there is *only one* `Rc` in existence at that point.

You can get around this with `Cell` or `RefCell`, which provide [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html).  `RefCell` is more flexible but has more runtime overhead, since it implements Rust's borrowing rules at runtime, meaning it can also panic if you use it incorrectly.

This is what that would look like:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Foo {
    value: i32,
}

struct Bar {
    foo: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>,
}

struct Parent {
    foo: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>,
    bar: Bar,
}

impl Bar {
    fn new(foo: Rc<RefCell<Foo>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            foo
        }
    }
}

impl Parent {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut foo = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo { value: 2 }));
        let bar = Bar::new(foo.clone());

        Self {
            foo,
            bar,
        }
    } 
}
```

Since the struct you're trying to create is self-referential, the non-`Rc` way of handling this would involve [pinning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/) and `unsafe`.  Basically you would have to create the `Foo` at a stable memory location before you take any references to it, and `Pin<_>` is required to ensure that the memory location of a value never changes.  You likely would still need `RefCell` if you want the value to be mutable through both the `Parent` and the `Bar`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution i see viable, i'll use this. Thank you!